# slideshow is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a website in which on header div i want to add a slideshow.My code took and display the first Image but the slider did not work i put all the images in images folder here the .html file is

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>slideshow</title>
</head>
<body>
<img scr ="image/slider1.jpg" id = "img"/>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" scr="slideshow.js"></script>
</body>
```

and my .js file is this

```
var myImage = doucoment.getElementById("img");
var ImageArray = ["slider1.jpg", "slider2.jpg", "slider3.jpg"];
ImageIndex = 0;
function changeImage() {
    img.setAttribute("src", ImageArray[ImageIndex]);
    ImageIndex++;
    if (ImageIndex >= ImageArray.length){
        ImageIndex = 0;
    }
}
var ImageHandle = setInterval(changeImage, 3000);
```

Comment: typo : `doucoment`

Comment: and `scr` in `HTML`

Comment: Please use the browser's built in developer tools. This kind of errors is **immediately** visible in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You have a **typo** in your `HTML` and `JavaScript`..

**Change**

`scr` to `src`

**And**

`doucoment` to `document`

Here is modified **snippet**.

```js
  var myImage = document.getElementById("img");
         //   ^^^^^^^ typo here.
  
    var ImageArray = ["https://www.google.com.pk/logos/doodles/2016/2016-doodle-fruit-games-day-8-5666133911797760.3-hp.gif", "http://reservations.life/css/images/bg-01.jpg"];
    ImageIndex = 0;
    function changeImage(){
    img.setAttribute("src", ImageArray[ImageIndex]);
    ImageIndex++;
    if(ImageIndex >= ImageArray.length){
    ImageIndex = 0;
  }
}
    var ImageHandle = setInterval(changeImage,3000);
```

```css
img{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
//   ||| typo here.
<img src ="https://www.google.com.pk/logos/doodles/2016/2016-doodle-fruit-games-day-8-5666133911797760.3-hp.gif" id = "img"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,2000);

function nextSlide() {
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
    currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
}
```

```css
#slides {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.showing {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul id="slides">
    <li class="slide showing">Slide 1</li>
    <li class="slide">Slide 2</li>
    <li class="slide">Slide 3</li>
    <li class="slide">Slide 4</li>
    <li class="slide">Slide 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: instead Slide 1 , slide 2 ,,, give a images you can observe the effect

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
scr ="image/slider1.jpg"
scr="slideshow.js"
```

turn 'scr' into 'src'

JS:

```
doucoment.getElementById("img")
```

turn 'doucoment' into 'document'